# Image hard drive containing Acronis Secure Zone

Tags: clone, disk-image, partition-recovery, acronis-trueimage

I'm trying to image the hard drive which has System, Windows and Acronis Secure Zone partitions. On my original machine I have recovery menu prompt ["Please press F11..."]. I'm able to image it over without any issues but once I try to apply this image file to the other drive I'm not able to open Recovery Option; no 'Press F11 key...' message appears and system boots straight into Windows.

Below are the image methods that I tried so far:

1. Clonezilla
   smart backup
   raw backup
2. Acronis True Image
   raw/sector-by-sector backup
3. Ghost
   raw backup - crashes on recovery
4. Ghost for Linux
   raw backup

I would assume that if I backup sector by sector I should have a full image with mbr records and other extra stuff (i.e. Recovery Prompt). But every-time I try to apply the image I'm not able to use Acronis Secure Zone at all (I do see it under the Disk Management).

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have created A sector by sector image with Acronis and it failed?

Comment: @Ramhound That's right (unless I misconfigured something during backup/recovery process). I have a feeling that installation of the Acronis Secure Zone attached to SN of the hard drive or some other information that prevents it from running

Comment: Have you tried to create an image with everything except the secure section?

Comment: @Ramhound Yep, I tried that and it works perfectly. The thing is that I need this Secure Zone (which contains the system backup) as a recovery option for our clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issues with using HDD Raw Copy Tool made be [HDDGURU.COM](http://HDDGURU.COM)